# PlantUML, how to add a FontColor for a column in entity

Tags: plantuml

I have this my PlantUML file

```
@startuml
' avoid problems with angled crows feet
skinparam linetype ortho

skinparam class {
    FontColor<<generated>> #0000FF
}

entity "User" as users
{
  *id : uuid <<generated>>
  --
  *email : text <<unique>>
  password : text
}

entity "DishType" as dish_type {
  *id : uuid <<generated>>
  --
  *name : text <<unique>>
  image : text
}

entity "Dish" as dish {
  *id : uuid <<generated>>
  --
  *name : text <<unique>>
  image : text
  menu_price : float
  solo_price : float
  dish_type_id : uuid <<FK>>
}

entity "Ingredient" as ingredient {
  *id : uuid <<generated>>
  --
  *name : text <<unique>>
  available : bool
}

dish "Many" --- "One" dish_type
dish "Many" --- "Many" ingredient
@enduml
```

So... I want that some fields like `<<unique>>` or `<<generated>>`, `<<fk>>` must be red, or yellow, whatever the color. I search like skinparam class but it works only with entity all fields, not only one field.

Can you help please. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with `skinparam` since stereotypes don't apply to attributes. However, maybe the new stylesheets function will support something like this.

You could use a `!function` like the result below. It's not perfect, but might suit your needs. You could also do the same for the `<<unique>>` and other attributes.

```
@startuml
!function $generated($a)
!return "<color:#0000ff>" + $a + " <<generated>></color>"
!endfunction

' avoid problems with angled crows feet
skinparam linetype ortho

entity "User" as users
{
  *$generated("id : uuid")
  --
  *email : text <<unique>>
  password : text
}

entity "DishType" as dish_type {
  *$generated("id : uuid")
  --
  *name : text <<unique>>
  image : text
}

entity "Dish" as dish {
  *$generated("id : uuid")
  --
  *name : text <<unique>>
  image : text
  menu_price : float
  solo_price : float
  dish_type_id : uuid <<FK>>
}

entity "Ingredient" as ingredient {
  *$generated("id : uuid")
  --
  *name : text <<unique>>
  available : bool
}

dish "Many" --- "One" dish_type
dish "Many" --- "Many" ingredient
@enduml
```

[image]